# Bibtex doesn't like symbol in url

Tags: bibtex

I am writing an academic paper in mathematics, and I need to cite a collection of lecture notes. These were never published, and I can only find this one link to reach them. This is given by

> url = {https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~aptm3/docs/lecture-notes/PartIII-ProfiniteGroups.pdf}

in the citation. However, it seems latex really doesn't like the ~ in the url. The error it gives is "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]". At first I had no idea what was going wrong, but it turns out that deleting ~ (and nothing else) fixes everything. This is an issue, though, since the citation will no longer take you to the correct page if this ~ is gone. I tried using \ ~, but the url outputted in the bibliography ends up looking like

> [https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/\aptm3/docs/lecture-notes/PartIII-ProfiniteGroups.pdf](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%5Captm3/docs/lecture-notes/PartIII-ProfiniteGroups.pdf)

This doesn't work either. Any idea on how I can cite this url without everything breaking?

Comment: Normally such urls work fine. But it can depend on your bibliography style and what it does with the field. So show a small but complete example that demonstrates your error.

Comment: You could try `%7E` instead of `~`. Percent encoding is only needed for non-ASCII characters, but it works for ASCII characters as well. But without knowing more about your document, it is difficult to help. Try to come up with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @JasperHabicht This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by using the percent encoding %7E for ~ in the url. Simply replacing ~ with %7E in the url took care of the error, and the link in the compiled document takes one to the correct page.

Thanks to @JasperHabicht for providing the solution!